# How do I find a London bank that offers accounts to a US person?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, banking

I'm a US citizen and I've moved to London. At some point I'm going to need a bank account here. If I use my usual information-seeking resources (mostly Google searches) I find that everyone and his dog are willing to write me an article informing me that most banks are unwilling to do business with US persons these days because of FATCA. I have yet to find a resource or article telling me which banks *are* willing to do business with me.

Obviously I could just try identifying all the banks there are in London and calling them up one at a time to inquire, but are there any resources I can use to expedite my search?

Comment: Lloyds have happily opened bank accounts for a few US citizens I know, without any great fuss or problems. Pretty sure on US citizen I know got an account with Nationwide without too many forms being needed either.

Comment: Anecdotally, I used HSBC and Santander when I was in the UK. I don't even live there anymore and I still have my Santander account.